# Is it still a probability distribution if one variable is used both as random variable and observation?

Tags: probability

$A$, $B$ and $C$ are random variables / Events. Is it still a probability (mathematically correct) to write a conditional distribution as
$$P(A,B|C,A)$$

What if I define an indicator function $\mathbb{1}$ and write
$$P(A,B|C,A)=\mathbb{1}_{A=a}P(B|C,A)$$
where $a$ is the a realization of $A$ and $\mathbb{1}$ is only true when $A=a$ hold?

Comment: If $A$ is a random variable then expressions like $P(A)$ (or more complex $P(A,B|C,A)$) have no proper meaning. At least I cannot think of any. The expression only makes sense if $A$ (or more complex $A,B,C$) is an event.

Comment: @drhab Thanks for your comment! What if they are events and $A$ appears on both side of $|$?  May I ask how to refer to the left side (A,B) and right side (C,A) of $|$?

Comment: In general $P(A\mid B)=P(A\cap B)/P(B)$. On base of this principle $$P(A,B\mid C,A)=P((A\cap B)\cap(C\cap A))/P(C\cap A)=P(A\cap B\cap C)/P(C\cap A)=P(B\mid C,A)$$So the $A$ on LHS of "|" just disappears. You could say that under the *condition* (on RHS) that $A$ will occur it becomes irrelevant to mention (on LHS) that $A$ will occur.